# Why do I keep getting this error message ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why do I keep getting this error message

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

This is the query I have...

```
INSERT ALL
INTO ACADEMIC_SESSION (SESSIONID, SESSIONNAME) VALUES (200, 'FALL SESSION'),
INTO ACADEMIC_SESSION (SESSIONID, SESSIONNAME) VALUES (300, 'SUMMER SESSION')
SELECT * from DUAL;
```

I can't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: What do you want to insert to the table? Why do you need the select statement?

Comment: @TeeKea, the select is required for this type of "insert all" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax; use one of these:

```
SQL> create table academic_session
  2    (session_id number,
  3     session_name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into academic_session (session_id, session_name)
  2  select 200, 'fall session' from dual union all
  3  select 300, 'summer session' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into academic_session (session_id, session_name)
  3      values (400, 'spring session')
  4    into academic_session (session_id, session_name)
  5      values (500, 'winter session')
  6  select * from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Ok, that works! The last syntax you gave me looks exactly like mine, what am I missing?

Comment: You aren't missing anything; you have a comma (between two INSERTs) too much :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no comma `,` between the `INTO` statements

```
INSERT ALL
INTO ACADEMIC_SESSION (SESSIONID, SESSIONNAME) VALUES (200, 'FALL SESSION')
INTO ACADEMIC_SESSION (SESSIONID, SESSIONNAME) VALUES (300, 'SUMMER SESSION')
SELECT * from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert two rows into the table, you may do so like this:

```
INSERT INTO ACADEMIC_SESSION (SESSIONID, SESSIONNAME) 
VALUES (200, 'FALL SESSION'), (300, 'SUMMER SESSION');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this as well. I actually copied and pasted what you wrote and got this error message ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. It allows me to insert one row, but I have multiple rows and that will take forever.